# Pegar imagens de uma pasta com javascript e exibir em um Slide

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Eu tenho um slide que funciona normalmente. Só que tenho que ficar passando pra ele o link de cada imagem.

O que eu queria fazer é colocar um caminho de uma pasta pra ele identificar os arquivos em png ou jpg e exibi-las automaticamente com javascript.

O Código está assim:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">

  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #000;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1/">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/sports/2/">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800/sports/3/">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
    
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>

  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: A pasta está no servidor? acredito que vc deva usar alguma linguagem no servidor, php .... . Se usar javascript e ele for executado no browser, você não tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos.

Comment: Ela está em uma pasta local. Não posso usar PHP, pois estou desenvolvendo pra um app.

Comment: Vai executar num browser?

Comment: Sim. Ai preciso que seja em Javascript. Pra identificar as páginas em uma pasta e  jogar elas direto no slide.

Comment: Uma solução seria usar um *input file multiple*, dai você teria acesso a todos os arquivos, mas teria que selecioná-los

Comment: Mas n vou fazer upload direto. Eu faria manualmente colocando na pasta imagens. Eu só jogarias as imagens lá dentro e o slide reconheceria.

Comment: Só com JavaScript no client-side você nao tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos.

Comment: Este link pode ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript

Comment: Se for puxando de uma página especifica. Tipo um link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um *loop* para inserir as imagens em sequência. Tudo que tem a fazer é definir em `var num_imagens` o número de imagens que quer inserir.

Por exemplo, quer inserir `3` imagens, defina `var num_imagens = 3;`.

Veja:

```js
var num_imagens = 3;
function carregaImgs(){

   var img_div = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-wrapper")[0];
   
   for(var x=1;x<=num_imagens;x++){
      var img_container = '<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-zoom-container">'
      +'<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800/sports/'+x+'/">'
      +'</div></div>';
      
      img_div.innerHTML += img_container;
   }
}


window.onload = function(){
   carregaImgs();

   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
   });

}
```

```css
html, body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
 }
 body {
   background: #000;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   color:#000;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .swiper-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .swiper-slide {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">
<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   </div>
   <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
   <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
   <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OliverDamon O código só vai pegar imagens, e não sites ou imagens dentro de sites, e no padrão acima. Vou excluir a resposta pois não foi util. Abs!

Comment: @OliverDamon O código só vai funcionar se as imagens estiverem no mesmo endereço e em sequencia: 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: Foi útil sim. Ajudou bastante. Mas poderia me ajudar em pegar tb imagens dentro de um link? Pois estou montando um site e pra isso preciso puxar o conteúdo do meu site externo.

Comment: Alguma maneira de puxar todos os resultados da pasta em questão? Esse código que vc mandou passou tão perto.

Comment: @OliverDamon Vou ver aqui...

Comment: Vlw. Obrigado! Estou tentando isso tem tempo.

Comment: @OliverDamon é tudo no servidor né? não tem nada local não neh?

Comment: Isso. Td vou puxar de um servidor externo. Mas precisa ser em javascript.

Comment: @OliverDamon O problema é o seguinte: não tem como saber que imagem que vc quer apenas colocando um link de um site, pois pode ter várias imagens no link.

Comment: Fiz isso. Mas não funcionou... n entendi o pq.

Comment: @OliverDamon em vez de `<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800/sports/'+x+'/">` ficaria `<img src="http://unionmangas.net/leitor/mangas/One%20Piece/887/00'+x+'.png">`

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de identificar e automaticamente puxar todas nos formatos? N precisa ser em ordem.

Comment: @OliverDamon Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔.